# Unmapping filetype mappings

Tags: vimscript, autocmd

I'm trying to unmap some key sequences mapped by `python` filetype plugin. While I know a better way, I'm still curious if it can be done with autocommands. Here's what I've got so far:

```
augroup python_ftplugin
    autocmd!
"\       for m in ['[[', '[]', '[m', '[M', ']]', '][', ']m', ']M']
    autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.py
\       for m in ['[[']
\           | if !empty(maparg(m, 'n'))
\               | execute 'nunmap <buffer> ' . m
\               | echom expand('%') . ': unmapped ' . m
\           | else
\               | echom expand('%') . ': not unmapped ' . m
\           | endif
\       | endfor
augroup END
```

The thing is, when I do [`:lvimgrep ... *.py`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#:lvimgrep), filetype plugin gets executed after my autocommand for the first matched file. Is there a way to remedy this?

Comment: You might want to share what `lvim` is

Comment: @D.BenKnoble See updated question.

Comment: Could you change your title from *Event after :lvimgrep has opened the first file* to something more specific *Unmap python filetype mappings*?

Comment: @Hotschke The thing is, I'm particularly interested in why using `BufNewFile,BufRead` is not enough or wrong in this case. I saw the [other question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7276/i-cannot-unmap-a-key-combination-yc-g/7277) where there's a hint (not only hint now) at solving my X (of XY) problem. But from what I can see now, I most likely used the wrong events. `FileType` event is most likely to be used in this case. I'm also interested in why in this particular case filetype plugin executed after `BufRead`, but the answer probably: "That's just the way it works."

Comment: For the question about the order of events see https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4493/what-is-the-order-of-winenter-bufenter-bufread-syntax-filetype-events. However, I cannot see why you need a specific event after `:lvimgrep` and the first file has been opened in your case. This is really looks like an XY problem.

Comment: I had a look into the order of events and yes it is unfortunately somewhat unexpected: there is a difference between opening a single python file versus running `:lvimgrep`. See details in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### UPDATE 24.3.2019

Vim has updated its Python runtime file [$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/python.vim](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/ftplugin/python.vim) in commit [63b74a8](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/63b74a8362b14576b21d342dc424d0396ca8ea27) (vim patch should be at least `8.1.1048`) which now respects the variables

- `g:no_plugin_maps`
- `g:no_python_maps`

If you set one of them in your vimrc to `1`, the mappings will not be created.

#### Unmap via autocmd Filetype python

```
augroup python_ftplugin
    autocmd!
    autocmd Filetype python
\       for m in ['[[', '[]', '[m', '[M', ']]', '][', ']m', ']M']
\       | execute('silent! unmap <buffer> '.m)
\       | endfor
augroup END
```

I have used `unmap` instead of `nunmap` because there are also `xmap` and `omap` which you might also want to unmap.

#### Order of events and when `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/python.vim` is sourced

```
augroup python_ftplugin
    autocmd!
    autocmd Filetype python echom "Event Filetype python"
    autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.py echom "Event BufNewFile,BufRead *.py"
augroup END
```

and add following echom to `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/python.vim`:

```
" Vim filetype plugin file
" Language: python
" ...

echom "Sourcing $VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/python.vim"
```

It is very interesting to see that there is a difference between

```
$ vim myfile.py
```

[image]

```
:lvimgrep class *.py
```

[image]

[Sato Katsura has expressed this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4493/what-is-the-order-of-winenter-bufenter-bufread-syntax-filetype-events?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment6681_4495) as following

> Contrary to the popular belief, the order of applying autocmds across multiple files is not well-defined.

#### Unmap in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim`

However, if you have many autocommands, filetype is tested for each autocommand, which is not efficient. Furthermore, you replicate something that Vim already does automatically anyway (see the reddit post [where_to_put_filetype_specific_stuff](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/wiki/where_to_put_filetype_specific_stuff) by romainl).

Therefore, it is recommended to do this in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim`

```
for m in ['[[', '[]', '[m', '[M', ']]', '][', ']m', ']M']
  execute('silent! unmap <buffer> '.m)
endfor
```

#### Add variable to `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/python.vim` to disable mappings

**Update** This section is outdated; upstream has incorporated this.

Actually, `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/python.vim` should follow the recommendation given in

`:h write-filetype-plugin`

> The user must have a chance to disable the mappings in a filetype
>   plugin, without disabling everything.  Here is an example of how this
>   is done for a plugin for the mail filetype: >
>
> ```
> " Add mappings, unless the user didn't want this.
> if !exists("no_plugin_maps") && !exists("no_mail_maps")
>   " Quote text by inserting "> "
>   if !hasmapto('<Plug>MailQuote')
>     vmap <buffer> <LocalLeader>q <Plug>MailQuote
>     nmap <buffer> <LocalLeader>q <Plug>MailQuote
>   endif
>   vnoremap <buffer> <Plug>MailQuote :s/^/> /<CR>
>   nnoremap <buffer> <Plug>MailQuote :.,$s/^/> /<CR>
> endif
> ```

If you can convince the current maintainer (https://github.com/tpict/vim-ftplugin-python) to make the mappings optional, you only have to place `let no_python_maps = 1` to your vimrc.

#### Do you really need the builtin `[[,[],]],][,[m,[M,]m,]M` for python?

I would highly appreciate if you could add a python code snippet to your question illustrating where you want to use the builtin motions. Otherwise I consider your question unmotivated. Do you know the motions `[{` and `]}`?

For an illustration what the mappings of the filetype plugin python do, see here [End of python block motion](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7262/end-of-python-block-motion/14115#14115). IMHO they are *very* useful [not only for python](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/17774/how-to-delete-entire-function-definition-c-style).

### Update: Convenient Cycling Through Quickfix/Location List

As it has turned out the OP is using `[` and `]` to cycle through the location list. As I said in the comments I would not advice to use them for this because [they](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/index.txt.html#%5B) are [*namespace*](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/index.txt.html#index) keys similar to [`z`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/index.txt.html#z) and [`g`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/index.txt.html#g).

Suggested alternatives:

1. [vim-unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) `[l` and `]l` (`[q` and `]q` for quickfix) (maybe with [repmo-vim](https://github.com/Houl/repmo-vim))
   Pros: no known conflicts with others
   Cons: too much weak finger movement and keys
2. [vim-qf](https://github.com/romainl/vim-qf) `<C-Home>` and `<C-End>` (`<Home>` and `<End>` for quickfix)
   Pros: no known conflicts with others
   Cons: too much hand movement
3. http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Short_mappings_for_common_tasks#Quickfix (function key)
   Pros: common scheme (e.g. `F3` in PyCharm & `F4` in Sublime Text) and less conflicts
   Cons: too much hand movement
4. [ale-inspired](https://github.com/w0rp/ale#5ix-how-can-i-navigate-between-errors-quickly)

   ```
   nmap <silent> <C-k> :lprevious<CR>
   nmap <silent> <C-j> :lnext<CR>
   ```

   Pros: home row keys (in particular when capslock is remapped to ctrl)
   Cons: already used by others (e.g. [ale](https://github.com/w0rp/ale#faq-navigation), [switch between splits](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Switch_between_Vim_window_splits_easily#Ctrl.2Bkjhl_Navigation), [vim-tmux-navigator](https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator)/[pilot](https://github.com/urbainvaes/vim-tmux-pilot), [edgemotion](https://github.com/haya14busa/vim-edgemotion))

   [vim-syntastic](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic#faqlnext) does not dare to suggest any specific mapping (except mentioning vim-unimpaired) but certainly sees a motivation for this.
5. Leader to space plus `j/k` (or `n/p`)

   ```
   let mapleader = "\<space>"
   nnoremap <leader>j :lnext<CR>
   nnoremap <leader>k :lprevious<CR>
   ```

   Pros: space bar by strongest finger and jk are home row keys
   Cons: possibly already used but others are also available (e.g. `ln/lp`)
6. macOS:

   - MacVim: `<Ctrl-Cmd-Left/Right>` for quickfix (default)
     `<Alt-Cmd-Left/Right>` for location list (add to gvimrc)
   - Xcode-inspired: `<Ctrl-Cmd-G>/<Ctrl-Shift-Cmd-G>` Find next/previous in workspace

Comment: These `[[` motions are indeed look pretty interesting. But I'm a heavy user of `:lvimgrep`, and up until now I've been using `[` and `]` to cycle through the matches. And these extra motions added by Python plugin were in the way. After pressing `[` it waited if I were to press `[` or something, or that's it. I wonder why builtin motions didn't lead to this though. So, cycling through matches in Python files became a drag. But they are indeed interesting, I've got to give them a try. But you know, the number of keyboard keys is limited. It's hard to decide what to use, and what not...

Comment: Thanks for the details. You did not mention that you have remapped `[` and `]` to a custom command. BTW, you also have to do this for ruby, vimscript and a few others. I would not recommend this. There are even more builtin square bracket motions. Please have a look at [`:h [`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/index.txt.html#%5B). I count 23 pairs of builtin mappings which you all remove. I  really like the plugin [vim-unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired/blob/master/doc/unimpaired.txt#L18-L59) which adds even more. You might be interested in `[l` and `]l`.

Comment: Also you might like repeating them with `;` and `,`: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/18162/repeat-complicated-motions

Comment: I would also recommend to you to read chapter 29.3 of the vim user manual. This might convince you not to change the meaning of `[` and `]`: [`:help 29.3`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_29.txt.html#29.3)

Comment: I have added a few suggestions for mappings to conveniently cycyle through the location list. However, if you have engraved them in your memory muscle, it will take effort to change to others.